# Apache2 stopped working after upgrade to v2.4 ((38)Function not implemented: AH00141)

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, grub, grub2

I was happily running apache2 and mysql on a Ubuntu 16.04 server with no problems, but yesterday I noticed that there were a bunch of updates available and I installed them using `apt-get`.

One of the updates was apache2, upgraded to `2.4.46`. Since then, apache stopped working. It returns this error when I try to start it: `(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator`. After reading some post online, I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu version to 18.04, the process just finished, but the situation didn't change, apache is still not working with the same error.

I read to check if `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` are present on the system, and they are there.

I do not know what to do to have apache working again. Can someone help me? Maybe give me some direction on how to downgrade it, I don't know, I really have no idea.

Thank in advance,
S.

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is the kernel, too old to work with the latest Apache version. I see that I have a `3.13.xxx` and a `5.4.xxx` kernel available, but I cannot switch to the latest. Neither `update-grub` nor `update-grub2` seem to be able to change the kernel. I think I need some help with grub config to solve this problem.

I tried to edit `grub.cfg` and point `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` but it didn't work. I was wondering if changing it to

`GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-67-generic"`

(I can see that entry in `grub.cfg`) might work.

Comment: I am now doing another upgrade to 20.04 to see if something changes...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884176/apache-could-not-initialize-random-number-generator

Comment: I saw that thread, didn't check the solution because the OP was referring to a windows installation, I'll check soon, thanks.

Comment: No, my path is `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"` I don't see any strage char.

Comment: And upgrading to 20.04 did not solve my problem...

Comment: You should have test it the upgrade in a dev/test environment first but I guess you have a working backup of that server and if not I would encourage you to start taking/testing backups/restores. Have you tried to for example strace Apache? Perhaps it will return more inside into what is failing?

Comment: Be sure to run `update-grub` after you update /etc/default/grub.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchulman I did. And then I noticed some error from grub. I'm starting to think that restoring a backup and setting up a new VM from scratch might be the only safe thing to do.